# Weird prefix/suffix chars when pasting on a shell

Tags: command-line, bash

On a specific shell (*bash*) I somehow managed to have my clipboard content be surrounded by a `0~` prefix and `~1` suffix.

That is, I copy `Spanish Inquisi`... oops sorry `Spanish Democracy`, I get pasted: `0~Spanish Democracy~1`. Independently of the copy/paste technique, either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or selection + mouse-wheel.

I was curious to understand how that happened, and how that could be reverted.

Comment: Are you saying that doesn't happen in a different shell like `sh`?

Comment: That's a bug in Trusty's VTE package. For details see e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/1350334 or search for "bracketed paste mode" combined with "gnome-terminal" or "vte".

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: `printf "\e[?2004l"` seems to be the simple workaround, maybe add this to your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @dessert : I closed the terminal already, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dessert: LXTerminal

Comment: Wait, you can't reproduce the problem? What did you do to solve it? Do you mind adding an answer below explaining your solution?

Comment: @egmont: I don't have the Midnight Commander thing installed! This might not be my case?

Comment: The special characters are definitely related to "bracketed paste mode", and there used to be a bug in VTE handling them (which was known to be triggered by Midnight Commander, but probably that's not the only use case of hitting this problem). It would be great if you could share further details with us: Which version of Ubuntu, which version of the terminal emulator (and VTE in turn), and what do you do exactly?

Comment: @dessert The issue was on a specific terminal: just closing it is enough. The question is right about how could that happen.

Comment: @egmont LXTerminal on Ubuntu 16.10 kernel  4.8.0-28-generic, bash shell 4.3.48.

Comment: Presumably you launched an app (maybe a text editor) that enabled bracketed paste, and this app exited unexpectedly (e.g. crashed) contains a bug so if left this mode enabled.